# Python memory allocation

Tags: python, pointers, memory

I am really interested how Python memory allocation works.

I have written 2 pieces of code:

1.

```
list = []
a = [1,2,3]
list.append(a)
a = [3,2,1]
print(list)
print(a)
```

2.

```
def change(list):
    list[1] = 50
    list[2] = 70

list = []
a = [1,2,3]
list.append(a)
change(a)
print(list)
print(a)
```

When I compile the first code i get result [[1,2,3]] and [3,2,1].

However, when I compile the second code the result I get is [1,50,70].

In the first case I create an object "a" and an array "list". When I append my object "a" to the array, array points at it in fact. Then, when I am assigning "a" new array [3,2,1], the object [1,2,3] is saved in the array and "a" points at new array [3,2,1].

In the second case I also create an object "a" and an array "list". I append "a" to array and there's also a pointer, that points at "a". Then I'm calling a method on an array "a". After calling the function and changing the value of the elements, array "list" still points at object "a" without creating a new instance.

Can somebody explain me the way it really works?

Comment: Memory allocation really isn't what you should be thinking about at this point. Read about [how variables and objects interact](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) first. Memory allocation is an implementation detail.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you don't understand? If I understood everything correctly, you already described how it works.

Comment: Those are not arrays, they are `list` objects. But in any event, please read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every variable you create in Python is a reference to an object. Lists are objects which contain multiple references to different objects.

Almost all operations in python modify these references, not the objects. So when you do `list[1] = 50` you are modifying the second reference that the list item contains.

I have found that a useful tool for visualising this is [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

So for your first example

```
list = [] # you create a reference from `list` to the the new list object you have created
a = [1,2,3] # you create a reference from `a` to the new list you have created which itself contains 3 references to three objects, `1`, `2` and `3`.
list.append(a) # this adds another reference to `list` to the object referenced by `a` which is the object `[1, 2, 3]`
a = [3,2,1] # create a reference from `a` to the new list you have created which itself contains 3 references to three objects, `3`, `2` and `1`.
print(list) # print the object referenced by `list`
print(a) # print the object referenced by `a`
```

For your second example

```
def change(list): # create a reference from `change` to a function object
    list[1] = 50 #change the second reference in the object referenced by `list` to `50`
    list[2] = 70 #change the third reference in the object referenced by `list` to `70`

list = [] # create a reference from `list` to a new list object
a = [1,2,3] # create a reference from `a` to a new list object which itself contains three references to three objects, `1`, `2` and `3`.
list.append(a) # add a reference to list to the object pointed to by `a`
change(a) # call the function referenced by change
print(list) # print the object referenced by `list`
print(a) # print the object referenced by `a`
```

Comment: That Python Tutor is worth several upvotes!  Nice tool, really :-)